# Javascript Hoisting on self executing function

Tags: javascript, closures, hoisting, self-executing-function

```
console.log(d, 1);    // undefined 1
var d = 8;
(function() {
  console.log(d, 2);  // undefined 2
  var d = 10
  console.log(d, 3);  // 10 3
})();
console.log(d, 4);    // 8 4
```

Could anyone please explain how this code produce the commented output ?

Comment: This code doesn't produce the commented output. Try it and see that it will produce a different output: https://jsfiddle.net/uvL8e885/ So either fix your comments or your code and ask a more specific question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have been trying this code in so many different ways, so somehow `d` stored to 10 on previous execution

Comment: `d` cannot be stored to `10` unless you make an assignment somewhere in your code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, you are very correct, I have tried removing `var` on `var d  =10` just before. brilliant!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important things to remember**

1. Any variable declared with `var`, will be `undefined` before the control reaches the line where it is defined, unless something else is assigned. This is because, in JavaScript, [declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).
2. Any variable declared with `var`, will be scoped to the function in which it is defined.

---

With this understanding, lets look at the code.

**First section**

```
console.log(d, 1);
var d = 8;
```

You access `d` before the line in which the `d` declared is executed. So, `d` will be `undefined`.

**Mid section**

```
(function() {
  console.log(d, 2);
  var d = 10;
  console.log(d, 3);
})();
```

Same thing here. You access `d` before and after the `d` is actually declared. That is why you are getting `undefined` and `10` respectively.

**Last section**

```
console.log(d, 4);
```

Since the variables declared within the functions will not be available outside the functions, in this line `d` will be the same variable declared at line 2. And the last assigned value is 8.

Comment: If I skipped adding `var` on line `var d = 10;`, then it gets value `8` and it seems `Mid section` will get the same value from `First section`. So when I add `var`, why the function is not executed in same scope and get value of `8`. Which rule precede there?

Comment: Because functions create their own scopes. If the variable you are trying to access is not defined anywhere within that function, it will go up and check in the previous scopes.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(d, 1); // undefined 1
//// d was not set yet, it has no value, wich is undefined

var d = 8;

(function() {

  console.log(d, 2); // undefined 2
  //// this function does not use the global scope, so there is no variable d set yet

  var d = 10

  console.log(d, 3); // 10 3
  //// now you the local variable d to 10

})();

console.log(d, 4); // 8 4
//// this gives the global variable from above (value 8) as you did not change it with the self executing function
```

Comment: On the first line we get `undefined 1`, so your explanation that `d` was set to `10` is kind of strange. Did you try running your code?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, but that obvious that d has to be 10, he just forgot that. I added it in the meantime and commented on it

Comment: There's nothing obvious. I cannot see any `var d = 10;` assignment in the OP before the first `console.log`. So let's try not to be guessing but rather you could ask the OP if this is the case instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ... no comment

Comment: And yet you are commenting :-) The OP has now modified his original question with the proper comments. So don't hesitate to amend your answer accordingly because at its current state it kind of differs from the original code.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov He wanted to know why he gets the output 10, so I wrote that it must be like that because it is already set to 10 ;) I dont think it was wrong to say this. But of cause I now changed it to his new code.

Comment: ok, now your answer corresponds to the OP. removing my downvote.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'd expect you to upvote this great answer :P

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have `undefined 2` is because of having `var d = 10` inside this function.

It means that this variable will be declared in the same scope, but later.

**P.S:** If you want to output `8 ...` everywhere, just remove this inner `var d = 10` and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is what the Code looks like to the Engine:

```
var outer_d;
console.log(outer_d, 1);    // undefined 1
outer_d = 8;

(function() {
    var inner_d;
    console.log(inner_d, 2);  // undefined 2
    inner_d = 10
    console.log(inner_d, 3);  // 10 3
})();

console.log(outer_d, 4);    // 8 4
```

Comment: and how it will look if I remove the second `var` declaration? any idea?

Comment: if you don't declare the var d inside the function, then d inside the function will just reference the variable in the outer scope. Accessing it, modifying it, ...